# Proving the set of "distance functions" on a compact set is a compact set itself

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

The problem statement.

Let $(X,d)$ be a compact metric space and $C(X)=\{\phi: X \to \mathbb R : \phi \text{ is continuous}\}$. For each $x \in X$ we define the function

$f_x: X \to \mathbb R$ $\space$ $\space$,
      $f_x(y)=d(x,y)$

Prove that the set $\mathcal F=\{f_x: x \in X\}$ is compact on $(C(X), d_{\infty})$

The attempt at a solution.

I don't know what to do here. I have in mind three characterizations/definitions of compactness I could use to show the given set is compact

1) prove that every sequence has a convergent subsequence
2) prove that from every open cover of $\mathcal F$ I can extract a finite subcover.
3) prove that $\mathcal F$ is complete and totally bounded.

I need some help with this exercise since I don't even know where to start, I don't want THE answer, just hints or suggestions that could guide me.

With David's suggestion I could do the following (though I am not sure if it's correct):

To prove $\mathcal F$, I need to show that every sequence in the space has a convergent subsequence, so let $\{f_{x_n}\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathcal F$. By hypothesis, $X$ is compact, so the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ has a convergent subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k \in \mathbb N}$. Suppose $x_{n_k} \to x$, lets prove that $f_{x_{n_k}} \to f_x$. Let $\epsilon>0$, we know that there exists $k_0 : \space \forall \space k\geq k_0, d(x_k,x)<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$.

By the triangle inequality, we have that $|f_{x_{n_k}}(y)-f_x(y)|=|d(x_{n_k},y)-d(y,x)|\leq d(x_{n_k},y)<\dfrac{\epsilon}{2}$ for all $k\geq k_0$. This means $d_{\infty}(f_{x_{n_k}},f_x)=\sup_{y \in X}|f_{x_{n_k}}(y)-f_x(y)|\leq \dfrac{\epsilon}{2}<\epsilon$ for all $k \geq k_0$. Then, $f_{x_{n_k}} \to f_x$, and clearly $f_x \in \mathcal F$, from here it follows that $\mathcal F$ is compact.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Do you understand the topology on the space of functions $C(X)$?

Comment: Yes, given two functions $f, g \in C(X)$, $d_{\infty}(f,g)=\sup_{x \in X} |f(x)-g(x)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it may help you to get a handle on this if you observe that the triangle inequality for a metric implies
$$
\forall y.\mid f_x(y) - f_z(y) \mid \le d(x,z)
$$

Comment: It never occured to me to use that. I've tried to prove it with your suggestion, if you want and have the time, I would appreciate if you can check my proof. Thank you, your suggestion was extremely useful.

Comment: well done. your proposed solution shows you have an excellent basic understanding of the topic. i think the proof is sound (though i am no expert!). there are a couple of typos which you might like to locate, as these make nonsense of your argument as it stands. we all make typos, so no sweat, but proofs require meticulous copy-editing, and this is a good habit to get into.

Comment: you might also examine why you have used $\frac{\epsilon}2$ rather than just $\epsilon$, as this sophistication is unnecessary here, although it doesn't affect the validity of your argument. also (just a suggestion) use a nickname or your real name - these "userXXXXX" monnikers are hard to remember